# TypeScript: Recursively mark single named property as required

Tags: typescript

Given a type like:

```js
type Book = {
  __typename?: 'Book';
  author?: {
    __typename?: 'Author';
    name?: string;
  };
};
```

I want to remove the optional flag from the `__typename` properties, recursively. Resulting in:

```js
type TypedBook = DeepMarkRequired<Book, "__typename">;
// type TypedBook = {
//   __typename: 'Book';
//   author?: {
//     __typename: 'Author';
//     name?: string;
//   };
// };
```

`ts-essentials` has [MarkRequired](https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials#MarkRequired), but it's not recursive, and when I try a simple implementation like:

```js
type DeepMarkRequired<T extends object, K extends PropertyKey> = MarkRequired<
  { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object ? DeepMarkRequired<T[P], K> : T[P] },
  K
>;
```

TypeScript complains on line 3 that `K` doesn't satisfy `keyof T`, which makes sense since `Required` and `Pick` both require `keyof T` rather than `PropertyKey` to allow this to be generic. I'm not sure how to allow passing an arbitrary parameter name all the way down the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build this yourself with a combination of [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys), [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype), and [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) utility types, but the piece you're missing is that you need to do something like `Pick<T, Extract<keyof T, K>>` with [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) if you're not sure whether `K` is a key of `T` or not.

But I'd prefer to use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to write this, like:

```
type DeepMarkRequired<T, K extends PropertyKey> = (
  { [P in keyof T as Extract<P, K>]-?: DeepMarkRequired<T[P], K> } &
  { [P in keyof T as Exclude<P, K>]: DeepMarkRequired<T[P], K> }
)
```

This yields

```
type TypedBook = DeepMarkRequired<Book, "__typename">;
/* type TypedBook = {
    __typename: "Book";
} & {
    author?: DeepMarkRequired<{
        __typename?: "Author" | undefined;
        name?: string | undefined;
    } | undefined, "__typename">;
} */
```

which is the type you want.  If you want it to look more like your version you can force the compiler to cash out all those aliases by copying the type to a new type parameter [via conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) and then do an identity map over that:

```
type DeepMarkRequired<T, K extends PropertyKey> = (
  { [P in keyof T as Extract<P, K>]-?: DeepMarkRequired<T[P], K> } &
  { [P in keyof T as Exclude<P, K>]: DeepMarkRequired<T[P], K> }
) extends infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never
```

which yields

```
/* type TypedBook = {
    __typename: "Book";
    author?: {
        __typename: "Author";
        name?: string | undefined;
    } | undefined;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nA1lAvFA3gWAFBSgfX1EgDsBDAWwgH4AuKAcniQYG4c8yBXYACzgBOdDBzwEi4COSrCGAQR78BbUXmk16AZ2ACAliQDm7XFAC+x8zhzFoAEQgQwAWTIDEAJQgBHLroEQAEwAeABUAGigAaSgIAA9gKQDNKAAFAThIAVBIiBAAPlQoAApRdCgAbRSofShEXLgAMygQqDJkgFF4gTIAY2AglIjIvIBdAFphe0cXN08fP0DQypGhgtMoADJSiqqaupBG5taO2J6AGy4AiAHVkfop51cPb19-YJDl1bMcAEoY+MSyX0DQgAigAHkoNQMDtqiRavUmuC7hDlmYoPQSBAAG6gqzYGzNSQBZjINAPGbPeZvIKkiIAIkINnU9LyxgA9AAqKCEkLE0mFLAmPBMyTqej00n0iybETC1qKQSTByPWYvBbBIVibXiZmUDRQekKPiCelQAA+UC4JCuDX0gWMOrE6mE2j0hgtVptEDtWICjrE60t1tt9oCDNFpH1rJlnPZ+K5PMkRMgJIQZLl2sjUn1EqlAc4iqE9C1Tt1YtzhuNSmlqh1Lq0On0Bk9IZ9YYL6OD3t9Dpw6zjOCAA)